# Setting TApplication.ActionUpdateDelay > 0 triggers the OnUpdate even if I do not move the mouse

Tags: delphi

I have an TActionManager with one TAction defined.
This action is assigned to several TButtons on my form.
The ActionManager has an OnUpdate event assigned

I have noticed that when I execute the application the OnUpdate event is triggered only when I move the mouse.

But, if I assign a value greater than 0 to Application.ActionUpdateDelay (say in the FormCreate), then the OuUpdate event is continuously fired.

Why this happens?

Comment: My test application with XE2 fires OnUpdate continuously even when ActionUpdateDelay is 0. Which seems which should be the case according to the weird [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ActionUpdateDelay).

Comment: Actions are updated whenever the main message loop processes one or more messages and then goes idle waiting for a new message to arrive.

Comment: The documentation reads like they got a bug report, didn't really understand what was going on, tried adding a delay to see what happened, found it changed behaviour for the test app, and decided to enshrine the trial as a feature.

Comment: +Remy Lebeau yes this is my understanding of the whole thing, but *why* only when I raise  Application.ActionUpdateDelay above 0 the messages are processed even when I do not move the mouse? As said in my original message, if I leave Application.ActionUpdateDelay := 0 (the default), then no message are fired when the mouse is idle.

Comment: @FabioVitale just read Delphi sources for `TApplication`, there are checks for `ActionUpdateDelay ` value and they fork execution into two paths, compare those paths and find the answer. "Use the source, Luke". And while when you move the mouse there are messages it is still not meaning that when you do not move it there would not be - there still can be non-mouse messages or software-generated mouse messages. And also mouse can have jitter...

Comment: @FabioVitale the logic is triggered whenever the message loop processes **any** message, not just mouse messages.  The VCL uses message-based timers to implement delays like `ActionUpdateDelay`.

Comment: I think recent versions of the VCL fixed the bugs that meant maximised mdi children lead to action update busy loops. Which means that this property is pointless.